# How to get contact info from signatures

Tags: gmail, gmail-contacts

A colleague showed me how [Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#contact) captures info from a business card. Is there any way I can fill contact info the same way from an email signature?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for WriteThat.name:

http://writethat.name

It's a service that scans your incoming emails and adds their signature info to your Google Contacts address book automatically. (& supposedly also updates them over time). I haven't tried it, but have recently heard at least 5 people give it good reviews.

It's Google-centric, but since you're talking about Goggles, I assume that might be of interest to you.

Comment: This link is broken and marked as unsafe atm.

Comment: Well, the comment is almost 10 years old, and comes [~6 years before Google started marking sites that weren't secured by SSL as "unsafe"](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-sets-https-deadline/236225/)...so I'm not that surprised. 

For those reading, it appears the domain of the service I recommended in 2012 has been bought up by a blog for "buying traffic" purposes. Best to look into another solution.

Comment: Also, looks like [Contacts+](https://www.contactsplus.com/) will currently extract contact info from email signatures. I'm sure there are some other solutions, but that one came up at first glance.

Comment: Thanks @Lloyddobbler, just keeping this post up to date with info that is current in case others come across it like myself :)

Answer (score 2):

Using only a PC, there is a Firefox extension called [CleverContacts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/162143/) that claims to be able to parse any section of relevant text and convert it into a Gmail contact.

I haven't tried it, but it sounds like you should be able to just highlight the signature then click the clever contact button and it'll attempt to read the relevant info and after giving you a preview, put it into a Google Contacts

Comment: It looks good, but as a comment points out the privacy policy is not too... private: "We log and store usage data to help improve our product, including action performed, selected text, datetime and email."

Comment: This link is now broken. I wonder why Google haven't done this already - they have "lens" for business cards, this should be even easier...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it as I'm in the middle of a 3-week Android drought, but you should be able to point Goggles at the signature on your PC screen and it should treat it exactly the same as a business card.

Or did you mean a totally integrated (on the phone, or in GMail) solution?

Comment: I wanted to do it using only a PC

Comment: I do this, but it makes more sense if it was integrated into Gmail.... weird how it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just started trying [Copy2Contact](http://www.copy2contact.com/c2c-gmail/) ... need to cut&paste the signature block into a second textbox (setup as a gadget in gmail).

Seems to work ok but still early days using it (by me)...

Options available for other systems (outlook, salesforce... etc)

Comment: That only works with Outlook or Salesforce (still) FYI